# Accessing controls in Javascript/JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am facing a problem in Javascript and JQuery when i call a function on the "onblur" event of the textbox to multiply its value to another value in other textbox the code works fine without master page but after using master page i don't know how to search for the control when the id of the associated controls is being passed to the function,and one mode thing accessing the id of the control in the master page by JQuery using $("[id$=test]") gives me the error, the associated code.what i want to do is multiply 2 values 'txtquan1' and 'txtattherate1' and store the result in 'lblamnt1' and when i click on the submit button the value store in 'lblamnt1' get vanished,i have googleit and cant find the solution except Enableviewstate=True; but the problem still remains the same for time being i am using jquery on textbox.....plz help

code in aspx file is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            $("[class$=txtreadonly]").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
         });

         function funAmount(suffix, quantity, amount, totalamt) {

             var qty = document.getElementById(suffix + quantity).value;

             var amt = document.getElementById(suffix + amount).value;
             var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt);

             document.getElementById(suffix + totalamt).innerText = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total;
             document.getElementById('ddltaxtype').options[0].selected = "true";
         }

         function funtax(selectedvalue) {
             var value22 = document.getElementById(selectedvalue).value

             totalamount = 0;
             for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

                 var val1 = document.getElementById('lblamnt' + i).value;
                 if (val1 != "") {
                     totalamount = totalamount + parseFloat(val1);
                 }
             }

             var disc = document.getElementById('txtdiscount').value
             if (disc != "") {
                 totalamount = parseInt(totalamount) - parseInt(disc);
             }

             if (value22 == 'amount is tax Free') {

                 document.getElementById('lbltotalamnt').value = totalamount;
                 document.getElementById('lbltax').value = '0';

             }
             else if (value22 == 'amount is inclusive of tax') {

                 document.getElementById('lbltotalamnt').value = totalamount;
                 var calTax = (totalamount * 100) / 105;
                 document.getElementById('lbltax').value = parseFloat(totalamount) - parseFloat(calTax);
             }
             else if (value22 == 'amount is taxable') {

                 var calTax = (totalamount * 5) / 100;
                 calTax = parseFloat(calTax);
                 document.getElementById('lbltax').value = calTax;
                 document.getElementById('lbltotalamnt').value = totalamount + calTax;
             }
         }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 1080px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 253px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 244px;
            }
    * {
    padding:0;
  /*  margin:0;   */
}
        .auto-style6 {
            width: 337px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            width: 11px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">




    <div>

        <table align="center" class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Verify the custumer details and start billing"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Bill Number : "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblbillno" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Custumer Name"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcusname" runat="server" Text="Custumer Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Custumer Ph"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcusph" runat="server" Text="Custumer Ph"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Only 20 records can be inserted at a time"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4" colspan="4">
                    <table id="table1" align="left" class="auto-style1" border="1" bordercolor="grey">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">
                                Serial Number
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">
                                Select Quantity
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Item Name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                AT The Rate
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Amount
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                                <asp:Label ID="lblserialnumber" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe1',''),'txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtitem1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtquan1',''), 'txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lblamnt1" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="2"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan2" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe2',''),'txtquan2','txtatthe2','lblamnt2')"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtitem2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe2" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtquan1',''), 'txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lblamnt2" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="3"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan3" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe3',''),'txtquan3','txtatthe3','lblamnt3')"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtitem3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe3" runat="server" onblur="funAmount('txtquan3','txtatthe3','lblamnt3')"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lblamnt3" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>                            
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="4"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan4" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe4',''),'txtquan4','txtatthe4','lblamnt4')"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtitem4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe4" runat="server" onblur="funAmount('txtquan4','txtatthe4','lblamnt4')"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="lblamnt4" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="5"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan5" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe5',''),'txtquan5','txtatthe5','lblamnt5')"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtitem5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe5" runat="server" onblur="funAmount('txtquan5','txtatthe5','lblamnt5')"></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="lblamnt5" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox><nobr />

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder3" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder4" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder5" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                 <asp:Button ID="btnnext" runat="server" Text="New Row" style="margin-left: 6px" Width="59px" OnClick="btnnext_Click" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Enter the discount if any"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdiscount" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style7">

                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddltaxtype" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px"  onblur="funtax('ddltaxtype')"  Width="92px" ></asp:DropDownList>

                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsalescomm" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" Width="159px" ></asp:DropDownList><nobr />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcashmode" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" ></asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Total Tax : "></asp:Label><no br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lbltax" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text="0"  Width="62px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Total Amount"></asp:Label> <no br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lbltotalamnt" class="txtreadonly" runat="server" Text="0" Width="72px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                    <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnsave_Click" />

                                <asp:Button ID="btnsaveexit" runat="server" Text="Save & exit" OnClick="btnsaveexit_Click" Width="79px" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnexit" runat="server" Text="Exit" OnClick="btnexit_Click" />

                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works according to your requirement:

1.Use  ClientIDMode="Static" in the Page Directive.

2.Remove suffix from the funAmount, as control ids will not have the master page id appended.

```
        function funAmount(quantity, amount, totalamt) {           
        var qty = document.getElementById(quantity).value;
        var amt = document.getElementById(amount).value;
        var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt);
        document.getElementById(totalamt).innerText = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total;
        document.getElementById('ddltaxtype').options[0].selected = "true";
    }
```

3.Pass the controls to the function appropriately.Eg:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount('txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount('txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
```

4.Make sure the correct control ids are passed,from your code i see the value passed for "txtatthe2" is incorrect.

5.You should be using a grid control if your rows are going to grow dynamically!

Comment: i have already used it the problem is that as u can see that every onblur function is passing 3 values.if i use "txtquan1" then on the next onblur request this code will be invalid because it will be "txtquan2" and it will increment to 3 and so on and this is the main problem when the function passes "txtquan+any integer value" then the code should detect that like document.getElementById('<%= '+quantity+'.ClientID %>') but this gives me error, i have googled it but finds no solution....

Comment: 'quantity' is the receiving parameter in the javascript code......plz help sir....thanx in advance

Comment: sir i have uploaded my entire aspx file,and the first line was not being uploaded propery....sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your "onblur" function call and javascript function and tested. It works well now. Please find the below Child Page and let me know:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtquan1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtquan1',''), 'txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtatthe1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe1',''),'txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblamnt1" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function funAmount(suffix, quantity, amount, totalamt) {

     var qty = document.getElementById(suffix + quantity).value;

     var amt = document.getElementById(suffix + amount).value;
     var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat( isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt);

     document.getElementById(suffix + totalamt).innerText = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total;
     //document.getElementById('ddltaxtype').options[0].selected = "true";
 }
```

Comment: sir the statement 'var qty = document.getElementById(suffix + quantity).value;' is not executing at all,suffix has the value 'contentplaceholder1_txtquan1' then according to the statement qty access the control 'contentplaceholder1_txtquan1_txtquan1' but it is not executing,what i want to achieve is that to access the controls 'txtatthe1' and 'lblamnt1' for each row(int value increments) and again i want to mention that i want to access the control property in content page from the content page via javascript,is it not possible that we search according to the parameter value i.e 'txtatthe1'

Comment: Juned, Can you please post your entire Html (or Aspx) and Js? I'm not getting how this id 'contentplaceholder1_txtquan1_txtquan1' got generated.