# search for a control in content page from content page via a variable passed to the executing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have researched much about this but still finds no solution when the calling function passes 3 different parameters that posses the id of 3 control namely txtquan1,txtatthe1,lblamnt1 on the onblur of both the textbox controls for the first row(this repeats for N number of rows) then,how can the javascript executing function can search for the control which is in content page and the calling function is also in the content page. i have used this code but qty have no value at all.....plz assist me..

```
function funAmount(suffix, quantity, amount, totalamt) {
     alert(suffix);


     var qty = document.getElementById(suffix + quantity).value;
     alert(qty);
     var amt = document.getElementById(suffix + amount).value;
     var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(isNaN(amt) ? 0 : amt);

     document.getElementById(suffix + totalamt).innerText = isNaN(total) ? 0 : total;

}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtquan1" runat="server" onblur="funAmount(this.id.replace('txtatthe1',''),'txtquan1','txtatthe1','lblamnt1')"></asp:TextBox>
```

and also used this code but gives the error

```
var no = document.getElementById('<%=this.Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl(amount).ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: Whats this.id.replace('txtatthe1','') ?

Comment: sorry sir this is nothing but the sample code which was given in the answer asked by me. the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915509/accessing-the-controls-in-the-javascirpt-and-jquery-functions/35933948#35933948

Comment: the code in the link is not working at all

Comment: <script> var currentrow = quantity.match(/\d+$/)[0]; var qty = document.getElementById('<%=this.Page.FindControl("txtquan"+currentrow)%>').value; should work but the code just before treat currentrow as a c# valiable,i want the value of currentrow(see javascript variable)to be used here...can anyone assist me on this